# How to use formula for transfering data from Tab Sheet 1 to Tab Sheet 2?

Tags: excel

Date & Time        JOB NO      PENDING

12/23/13 2:14 PM   SICD-B00xxx    *

My question is, there are three cells named- Date & Time, Job No and Pending. When I tick(*) in Pending named cell, I need to copied automatically the data of Date & Time and Job No to Sheet 2 in the same cells from Sheet 1. Please advise me that which formula I can use and how?

Sheet 1 : Date & Time (O5), Job No (Q5) and Pending (S5)

Sheet 2 : The same as Sheet 1

When I give * in Sheet 1 S5, the other data should copied to Sheet 2 in O5 and Q5.

I want to use formula in sheet 1 S5 because I have already used a formula in sheet 1 O5, as IF(Q5<>"",NOW(),O5),"")

Please help me for sort out this issue.

Thank you

Comment: -1 because "give me the code"

Comment: -1 for no code attempt. Would have gone a second -1 for the lack of formatting if I could have

Answer (score 0):

Please try in Sheet2:

in O5:  `=IF(Sheet1!$S5="*",Sheet1!O5,"")` and
in Q5:  `=IF(Sheet1!$S5="*",Sheet1!Q5,"")`

also note the comments above and (a) =`IF(Q5<>"",NOW(),O5),"")` is not a valid formula and (b) though `I want to use formula in sheet 1` that is not possible.